# How can I create a join like query using LINQ and check for a propery in a child object?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two objects: Word and WordForm.  They are linked together with WordId. Here's an example of the data in these:

```
Word id      Word id Wordformid     Sourceid

1                1     123            1
                 1     234            1
                 1     567            2
                 1     890            2

2                2     111            1
3                3     113            1

4                3     222            2
```

I would like to create a LINQ Query that gives me all the Words where there is no corresponding WordForm having a particular SourceId. In other words a query that could give me:

If SourceId selector is 1 then it would give me `4`

If SourceId selector is 2 then it would give me `2 & 3`

Here's what I have so far:

```
var words = db.Words
            .Where(w => !db.WordForms.Any(z => z.WordId == w.WordId ))
            .ToList();


public class Word 
{
    public System.Guid WordId { get; set; } // WordId (Primary key)
    public string Name { get; set; } // Name (length: 20)
    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<WordForm> WordForms { get; set; } // WordForm.FK_WordFormWord 
}

public class WordForm
{
    public System.Guid WordFormId { get; set; } // WordFormId (Primary key)
    public System.Guid WordId { get; set; } // WordId
    public int         SourceId { get; set; } // Source
    public string Definition { get; set; } // Definition (length: 500)
    // Foreign keys
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; } // FK_WordFormWord
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Your code seems correct toi me.

Comment: var words = db.Words
            .Where(w => !db.WordForms.Any(z => z.WordId == w.WordId && w.SourceId != z.SourceId))
            .ToList();

Comment: Why down vote. Up vote from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all the Words where there is no corresponding WordForm having a particular SourceId

Let say you have `Word w`. The above can be translated like this:

*corresponding WordForm*:

```
db.WordForms.Where(wf => wf.WordId == w.WordId)
```

*WordForm having a particular SourceId*:

```
db.WordForms.Where(wf => wf.SourceId == SourceId)
```

*corresponding WordForm having a particular SourceId*:

```
db.WordForms.Where(wf => wf.WordId == w.WordId && wf.SourceId == SourceId)
```

*no corresponding WordForm having a particular SourceId*:

```
!db.WordForms.Where(wf => wf.WordId == w.WordId && wf.SourceId == SourceId).Any()
```

or simply

```
!db.WordForms.Any(wf => wf.WordId == w.WordId && wf.SourceId == SourceId)
```

So the whole query would be:

```
var words = db.Words
    .Where(w => !db.WordForms.Any(wf => wf.WordId == w.WordId && wf.SourceId == SourceId))
    .ToList();
```